# JSP Repository is not iniatlized

Tags: java, spring, list, jsp

I am trying to initalize my repository inside on of my JSP's. I have imported it above the code but yet it still says it is not initilized.
The code below is the top of the page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import="co2103.hw2.domain.TestResults" %>
<%@ page import="co2103.hw2.repositories.TestResultsRepository" %>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired" %>

<% TestResultsRepository TRRepo; <! DECLARED HERE
 int size = 100; 
for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) { 
List<String> list = TRRepo.findAllById(i); <! SAYS HERE THAT IT IS NOT INITALIZED
} 
System.out.println("List initalized!");
%>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I am new to programming Java so any help would be very appreciated.

TEST RESULTS REPOSITORY CLASS

```
public interface TestResultsRepository extends CrudRepository<TestResults, String> {
String findAllById(int id);

}
```

Comment: Try like this : `TestResultsRepository TRRepo = new TestResultsRepository();`

Comment: Thank you, I'm afraid I get the following error "Cannot instantiate the type TestResultsRepository;

Comment: can you show `TestResultsRepository` class?

Comment: @Swati I've added it to the main question.

Comment: Did you try autowiring it?

Comment: Hi, `TestResultsRepository` is interface not class you need  "implement" it by another class then you can access its method .Here [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) this for more info .